# Сохранение картинки в SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

Как сохранять картинки в `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте код, приведенный ниже, чтобы сохранить изображение во внутренней директории:

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // путь /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Создаем imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
       // Используем метод сжатия BitMap объекта для записи в OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
              fos.close(); 
        } 
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Для того, чтобы прочитать файл из внутренней памяти. Используйте код, приведенный ниже

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{
    try {
        File f=new File(path, "profile.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPicker);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/5698593)

---

Таким образом картинка тоже сохраняется в закрытых папках твоего приложения в системе, а уже в `SharedPreferences` можно сохранить путь к этой картинке т.е. то, что возвращает `saveToInternalStorage`.

`SharedPreferences` предназначен для хранения простых переменных типа `String`,`int`... Гораздо логичнее и, как я считаю правильнее, хранить там только путь к картинке, а саму картинку в исходном виде рядом с теми же настройками. "простой и легкий механизм, основанный на парах «ключ — значение» и предназначенный для сохранения примитивных данных приложения, чаще всего пользовательских настроек"

Comment: что вам не нравится? SharedPreferences предназначен для хранения простых переменных типа String,int... Гонраздо логичнее и, как я считаю правильнее, хранить там только путь к картинке, а саму картинку в исходном виде рядом с теми же настройками.

Comment: "простой и легкий механизм, основанный на парах «ключ — значение» и предназначенный для сохранения примитивных данных приложения, чаще всего пользовательских настроек" -  http://suvitruf.ru/2012/09/17/1916/

Comment: Думаю, что не нравится то, что вы просто скопировали часть ответа, не потрудившись даже перевести. А ресурс называется "Stack Overflow на русском", а не "копипаста с Stack Overflow"

Comment: @pavlofff Внес исправления

Comment: @YuraIvanov надеюсь всех все устраивает.